# Long polling issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, long-polling

I have strange issue, I'm doing long polling to check if something new appeared in MySQL table, everything works fine, I'm getting messages as soon as they appear in table. but problem is when I'm trying to reload my page (F5) I have to wait until server side function is completed and then my page refreshes.

For example my long polling start and I refresh page in first second of execution, I have to wait 29 seconds for page to refresh.

Does anyone knows whats going on?

Thanks in advance!

here is code

**php**

```
public function longPolling() {
    if (isset($_POST['timestamp'])) {
        $timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];
    }
    $end = time() + 20;
    while (time() <= $end) {
        $data = $this->db->select("SELECT id, status, error, start, end, ackby FROM event WHERE start > '$timestamp'", 0);
        if ($data) {
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'timestamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
            break;
        } 
        usleep(25000);
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
function startPoll(timestamp) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dashboard/longPolling',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 30000,
        cache: false,
        data: {
            timestamp: timestamp
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data != null && data.status == 1) {
                oTable.fnReloadAjax();
                timestamp = data.timestamp;
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
                startPoll(timestamp);
            }, 100)
        }

    });
}
```

P.S. `ignore_user_abort` is disabled.

Comment: What are you using for 'polling the table' - a mySQL events / triggers or some other method?

Comment: Without knowing the code it is hard to guess. It could be a locking problem of the session or db. That if you do long polling something is locked on the server. And that if you reload it waits until the lock is released.

Comment: I'm using simple while loop which checks if there is new timestamp in table

Answer (score 0):

It seems that on refresh the data you are showing is not persisted so you lose it while waiting for the changes happen in the back end, you are showing nothing